# NumpyDoc Checking for conformity to the doc spec?

Tags: python, numpy, python-sphinx, docutils, numpydoc

The Numpy project provides a specification for the the formatting of their documentation to support readability and automated extraction ([link](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/HOWTO_DOCUMENT.rst.txt)).  They also provide [Numpydoc](https://github.com/numpy/numpydoc), as an extension to Sphinx, to support extraction of some additional keywords.

Before starting to write an extension to docutils, does a library exist to help introspect existing docstrings and identify non-conformity to the Numpy standard.

Image a more mature library with extensive documentation that wanted to adopt the Numpy documentation spec.  One approach would be to introspect the library and generate a report describing the state of the doc strings.

This is reconnaissance question before starting to implement this as an extension to docutils or numpydoc.  Have I missed an existing solution or does an elegant solution exist?

Comment: I am not aware of an existing solution, but I would be very interested in this!

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I've come across is [`doccheck`](https://github.com/rmcgibbo/doccheck) by @robert-t-mcgibbon:

> Check that all docstrings satisfy Numpy format
>
> This is a small script that goes through functions, methods and classes in a package and looks for inconsistencies between the signatures and (Numpy format) docstring.

Comment: This may theoretically answer the question, but it would be best to include the essential parts of the answer here for future users, and provide the link for reference. [Link-dominated answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) can become invalid through [link rot](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).